# Browsify including jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, browserify

Hi there I am new to browserify and have been adding my code to be more structured, I read up on the docs for adding JQuery plugins but for some reason I get the following error when trying to add 'infinite-ajax-scroll' plugin as a "module".

**Edit:** The Plugin come from here:
https://github.com/webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll

I keep getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: jqueryIas is not a function

Here is my file:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
window.jQuery = $;
global.$ = require('jquery');
var jqueryIas     = require('../plugins/jquery.ias.min.js');

var moduleListings = (function() {

    (function($tvshow_episode_listing){

        if($tvshow_episode_listing.length)
        {
            var ias = jqueryIas({
                container:  '#tvshows-episodes-listing',
                item:       '.m-listing-item-row',
                pagination: '.m-pagination-tvshow',
                next:       '.next-page-link'
            });

            ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension({
                src: '/templates/default/images/loader.gif',
                html: '<div class="ias-spinner l-listing-loading"><img src="{src}"/></div>'
            }));

            ias.extension(new IASNoneLeftExtension({
                text: '',
                html: ''
            }));

            ias.extension(new IASTriggerExtension({
                offset: 1,
                text: 'Load More Episodes',
                textPrev: 'Load Previous Episodes',
                html: '<div class="ias-trigger ias-trigger-next l-tvshows-listing-nav l-episodes-listing-nav l-tvshows-listing-nav-next"><a>{text} <em class="f-tvrocks icon-chevron-down"></em></a></div>',
                htmlPrev: '<div class="ias-trigger ias-trigger-prev l-tvshows-listing-nav l-episodes-listing-nav l-tvshows-listing-nav-prev"><a><em class="f-tvrocks icon-chevron-up"></em> {text}</a></div>'
            }));

            ias.extension(new IASPagingExtension());

            ias.extension(new IASHistoryExtension({
                prev: '.prev-page-link'
            }));

            ias.on('rendered', function() {

                $('.ajax-watched-listing-toggle').off( "click");
                toggle_watched_episode( $('.ajax-watched-listing-toggle') );

                $('.tooltip').jBox('Tooltip', {
                    theme: 'TooltipDark'
                });
            });
        }
    })($('#tvshows-episodes-listing'));

});

module.exports = moduleListings;
```

Any ideas how I can require this plugin within browserify?